# eval function makes app not work on production environment

Tags: webpack, build, production, aurelia

I am deploying an aurelia app into production environment and I have faced the issue that the result code includes eval function calls and my production environment unfortunately doesn't allow that.

And I face this error on app run:

[image]

```
vendors~2a42e354.02107019925d746ff1ac.chunk.js:10 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

    at Object.GAND (vendors~2a42e354.02107019925d746ff1ac.chunk.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~app.02107019925d746ff1ac.bundle.js:85)
    at Object.0 (app~01e7b97c.02107019925d746ff1ac.chunk.js:44)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~app.02107019925d746ff1ac.bundle.js:85)
    at checkDeferredModules (runtime~app.02107019925d746ff1ac.bundle.js:46)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (runtime~app.02107019925d746ff1ac.bundle.js:33)
    at app~5a11b65b.02107019925d746ff1ac.chunk.js:1
```

Now I want to know if is there a way to build aurelia for production by excluding the eval functions?

## UPDATE

I guess that this may be about webpack. If it is, is there a way to change this configuration in webpack?

Comment: I guess not webpack, but your production server is adding the HTTP header `Content-Security-Policy`.

Comment: Depends on how complex is the string you eval, you can avoid eval by reusing Aurelia parser. https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/tap-into-aurelia-expression-parser/786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I and my coworker found the issue. Although it seems that issue is specific to our situation, I share it so it may help some other in findings similar issues:

The main problem was about that building project in development mode was the source of problem. The output of development type build includes `eval` function calls in many modules. It was enough that I do the build in production mode.

But the second mistake was that I was thinking that I am building in production mode while using this command:

```
au build --prod
```

I have missed this command up with Angular's CLI. And the correct command was:

```
au build --env prod
```

So the configuration of webpack was to not use eval calls on production environment.